# Is ‘data mart’ a synonym of ‘star schema’?

Tags: data-warehouse

Aren't we using star schemas or flocon schemas to create datamarts ?
So can we say that Datamarts are synonym of star schema? 
Yes or no, I need justification please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't say that Data Mart is a synonym of a star schema - it is a broader concept.

Data Mart is a specialized **data warehouse** - it's a platform that consists of hardware, software and data.

Star Schema is a data structure optimized for querying. It's one of the components of a Data Mart, and not the only type of structures available (i.e, you can use a flat table instead).

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand I had the answer no from my teacher but he just keep going without explanation